# PowerBI report load fails on Xamarin.ios with "This content isn't available" message

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, powerbi

We have Xamarin applications for Android and iOS and are basically using a WebView to display PowerBI reports in the application.

The HTML is stored in the bundle and the EmbedToken and EmbedURL are dynamically inserted in it via an API.

This was working fine until the day before yesterday but since then they have stopped working on iOS. A message saying "This content isn't available" shows up. Though the report works just fine on Web & Android.

Upon investigation, the same EmbedToken & EmbedURL work just fine and the report shows up in the sandbox environment in safari browser on the same iOS devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We too faced this issue.

Just make sure the underlying *WebView* renderer is using *WKWebView* and not *UIWebView*.

*UIWebView* has been deprecated for a while and looks the kill switch has been engaged now.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview